# Extracting date from the sql query string in python

Tags: python, sql, string

I have a case where I have to extract date from a SQL query that I am running through a python script.

This is the query:

```
select * from COLL_DS2 where TRANSACTION_DATE between '2021.02.28' and '2021.04.08' order by CREATION_DATE
```

I want to extract '2021.02.28' and '2021.04.08' from the query string.

Any help please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please share your code for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to write it.
Tim Biegeleisen solution is good, just need to add the import re

```py
import re
Query = "select * from COLL_DS2 where TRANSACTION_DATE between '2021.02.28' and '2021.04.08'"
ldat = re.findall('\d+\.\d+\.\d+', Query)

print(ldat)
# ['2021.02.28', '2021.04.08']
```

Comment: Yes, this one working. Thanks. In the above solution, I was getting an empty array.I already had re imported. I think it was because of `r` in the "re.findall" line which was causing the problem.

Comment: This is not the best or safest answer which can be given, because the regex pattern used here would match things like IP addresses e.g. `192.168.0.1` in addition to dates.

Comment: You are right for IP adresses but on the other hand you have also many format for dates : 2021.4.8, 21.4.8 etc...

Answer (score 1):

You may use `re.findall`:

```py
sql = "select * from COLL_DS2 where TRANSACTION_DATE between '2021.02.28' and '2021.04.08' order by CREATION_DATE"
dates = re.findall(r"'(\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})'", sql)
print(dates)  # ['2021.02.28', '2021.04.08']
```

Comment: Sorry it's returning an empty list.

Comment: @amiteshshukla [No it's not](https://rextester.com/BIYC68083).

Comment: I think it was because of r in the "re.findall" line which was causing the problem. The below answer is the updated version of your answer. But that one worked for me. So marked that one as right and upvoted your answer. Thanks for giving the solution though. Much appreciated @Tim Biegeleisen